# Python probability algo

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to calculate the probability of getting two 1s rolling two dices. I know that the probability formulat is

```
# Probability of an Event =  Number of Favorable Outcomes Total / Number of Possible Outcomes
```

I was able to come up with a solution algorithmically but cannot articulate the formula in the return statement. How would I go about this with this solution

```
import random 

def roll_dice(n, range):

    total_count = 0

    for i in xrange(range):

        while True:

            total_count +=1

            d1, d2 = random.randint(1,n), random.randint(1,n)

            if d1 == d2:
                break

    return #probability

print roll_dice(6, 1000)
```

Comment: At the return statement, how many favourable outcomes have been seen, and how many possible outcomes were there? What in your code detects a “favourable” outcome? And does it do this correctly according to what you are trying to calculate?

Comment: @barny people answered though, thank you lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the probability of getting two `ones` with this code. What your code (mistakenly, due to the `while True`) does is *count* how many attempts are necessary in order to get *any* two equal outcomes from two *independent* dice.

This probability can be determined with simple probability theory. For you to get *any* two equal outcomes, `p = (1/36) * 6 = 1/6`.

This means that it is expected that, out of every 6 throws of two independent dice, it will *once* happen that you get the same outcome from each (e.g. two `fours` or two `sixes`)

If you want to find that with an algorithm, you can run  a Monte-Carlo-like simulation to see the how many throws are expected for this to happen in random state of worlds.

Using your own algo (with some minor modifications) :

```
import random 

def roll_dice(n, arange):

    total_count = 0

    for i in range(arange):
        total_count +=1
        d1, d2 = random.randint(1,n), random.randint(1,n)
        if d1 == d2:
            break

    return total_count

z=[]
s=1000
for i in range(s):
    z.append(roll_dice(6, 1000))

>>> np.array(z).mean()
5.916666666666667

# s=100000
>>> np.array(z).mean()
5.9943
```

You'll see that, as expected, the greater the number of simulations, the closer the mean is expected to get to 6.

---

In addition, if you want to find the average for the case your describe (i.e. to find probability of two `ones` coming out), you can change this line (which accounts for *any two equal numbers*)

```
if d1 == d2:
```

for the following (which accounts for only the case where output is `one`):

```
if d1 == d2 and (d1==1):
```

Then, you can run and find that

```
>>>  np.array(z).mean()
35.8479
```

which is close to `36`, as expected.

Notice that if you plot an histogram of your outcomes, results will not follow a normal distribution:
[image]

This happens because you are analyzing the probability of `X*Y` being equal to one, and `X*Y` is the product of two gaussian random variables. Thus, the distribution of `X*Y` is not normal, but will follow the *[product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)* of these two variables (refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101062/is-the-product-of-two-gaussian-random-variables-also-a-gaussian))

Comment: Good catch, since in the original code it does not look for an instance where both `d1` and `d2` are one; it only looks to see if `d1` and `d2` are the same.

Comment: @RafaelC this is awsome I changed my condition to be d1 == 1 and d2 == 1

Comment: I don't think it follows quite as you stated it that the expected number of rolls is 6, given the probability that the probability of rolling a double is 1/6 (although that conclusion is true). It looks like you use "It is expected that" in an informal sense, and then conclude something about expectation in the statistical sense. I think you need to write down and solve the equation E = 1/6 + (E+1)5/6, or compute the sum `\sigma_{k=1}^\infty k*(1-p)^{k-1}p`. Or perhaps I'm missing some intuition that you have.

Comment: @PaulHankin indeed you are correct, but your expression basically proves the intuition behind my (admittedly *bad*) wording. If we calculate your infinite sum, we find that the result is `1/p`, for any `p` such that `|1-p|<1`. In this case, for  `p=1/6`, we get `6`. I used *expectation* to refer to the *mean* of the simulation, which is also consistent to our results

Answer (score 1):

The probability is the same no matter how many times you roll the dice. 1/36. 1 favorable outcome divided by 36 possible ones. Rolling the dice that many times to calculate it would end up looking more like a  [Bell Curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution). If that is what you want the count the times you get 2 1s and divide by the range.

EDIT: CODE ADDED

```
def roll_dice(n, range):
     total_count = 0

    for i in xrange(range):
        d1, d2 = random.randint(1,n), random.randint(1,n)
        if d1 == 1 and d2 == 1:
            total_count+=1

return total_count/range
```

Comment: so you mean total_count/range?

Comment: yes, total count of double 1s/range. But do not expect it to be near 1/36.

Comment: That's true theoretically but are we addressing this experimentally?

Comment: @khepu I know this won't get exact but atleast i can adjust range to get it close, so total_count/range gives me a whole number how do I go about turning this into a percentage

Comment: @Mangohero1 yes experimentally

Comment: @e_mam106 it will give you a result from 0 to 1 which is the percentage now if you want something like 30% just multiply by 100.

Comment: @Mangohero i have tried rolling a die a few thousand times in java and the result was indeed a bell curve. Maybe this is because random in most languages is pseudo-random. perhaps if you used a secure random you would get a flat line but i highly doubt it.

Comment: @Khepu actually `range` won't matter here. Its just a limit for how many attempts you'll try before giving up. It will not yield the probability

Comment: @RafaelC yeah you are right, i did think of that but way too late.